# Read XML node in SQL Server 2000 TEXT column

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2000

I've been tasked with extracting some data from a legacy system that has been mothballed for some time - all of the data that we want is stored in a TEXT type column in one table, and the average string length is around 7000 characters.  The XML is encoded in UTF-16.

This is my first time working with XML in SQL Server and I'm stuck with SQL Server 2000 while I do it, which doesn't seem to be making life any easier.

I got as far as this example, with some obviously inherent flaws:

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(4000), @i INT
SELECT TOP 1 @xml = CONVERT(NTEXT,[Content]) FROM UPLSalesP.dbo.RSSDocument

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @i OUTPUT, @xml

SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@i, '/UPLFolder/UPL/ApplicationData', 1)
```

The NVARCHAR limit is too small for what I'm trying to achieve for one.  Second when I run what I've got I get the following error:

```
Msg 6603, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_xml_preparedocument, Line 4
XML parsing error: A name contained an invalid character.
```

I don't know if this is an encoding problem or a result of the obvious truncation of the XML.  Can anyone help me out in anyway?  Some examples would be extremely useful!

Comment: It may make more sense to write some code, as sql server's xml support will not be as robust as an actual programming language.

Comment: Probably a truncation error; do you have an instance of SQL 2005+ that can read the data from the SQL 2000 instance?  The XML handling became much more robust in 2005.

Comment: I could link it into SQL Server 2008 R2 Express - what method would work best interpreting it that way?  I tried just getting into XML in 2008 as follows `SELECT TOP 1 Id, CONVERT(XML, Content) FROM [UPLSalesP].[dbo].[RSSDocument]`

and got this in response `XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding`

Got any examples I can check out because I'm lost on this one!

Comment: What happens if you first cast to nvarchar and then to XML?

Comment: The author of this post had the answer: http://stgaup.blogspot.co.uk/2008/05/sql-server-2005-xml-msg-9402-unable-to.html